# YAP: Permission denied after recompilation

Tags: errors, miktex, texniccenter, yap

Some time ago I installed MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXnicCenter 2.0 beta (64bit) and YAP 2.9.4206. Since then I've had a problem with recompiling. That is, if YAP is already running and displaying my .dvi-file, and I click Build and View in TC, I frequently (about 50 % of times) get the following error message:

> MiKTex Problem Report
>
> Permission denied: C:\Users...\ProximinalStuff.dvi

If I close YAP before recompiling, then there is no problem. But I don't want to do that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you try entering this to your Profiles--Viewer--View project's output--Command: `[Open("%bm.dvi",0,1,1)]`. Save the original command before.

Comment: Maybe you want to upgrade TC to the stable version 2.02. Before you do the work. Then search the internet on how to tell YAP the parameters for TC. After this, configure TC as described here: http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/configuration.html

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem when I switched the render method to 'Dvips' (for psfrag command).

The problem went away after I switch back to 'pk' in Dvi->View->Render method